# Toggle Div visibility upon radion button select issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have managed to create a Div visibility toggle with the following code :

```js
$('input[name="type"]').on('change', function() {
    var show = $(this).val();
    $(".typechoice").hide();
    $("#"+show).show();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio"  name="type" value="solo" checked ;> solo<br>
<input type="radio"  name="type" value="company" ;> company<br>

<div id="solo" class="typechoice">Solo</div>
<div id="company" class="typechoice">Company</div>
```

It works perfectly but not when the page is loaded the first time (both Div are visible instead of a single Div only then). I think it is because `onchange` is used in the JS (I am no expert and grabbed bit on different stack overflow threads)

How can I have this code work when a radio button is already checked on the page before the user action any?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just trigger the change event of checked checkbox using the following line to hide the other div initially.

```
$('input[name="type"]:checked').change()
```

**FULL CODE**

```js
$('input[name="type"]').on('change', function() {
  var show = $(this).val();
  $(".typechoice").hide();
  $("#" + show).show();
})
$('input[name="type"]:checked').change()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="type" value="solo" checked ;> solo
<br>
<input type="radio" name="type" value="company" ;> company
<br>

<div id="solo" class="typechoice">AAAA</div>
<div id="company" class="typechoice">BBBB</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be simplest to just call `change()` on the checked radio in `document.ready()`

```js
$(function(){
  $('input[type=radio]:checked').change();
});

$('input[name="type"]').on('change', function() {
        var show = $(this).val();
        $(".typechoice").hide();
        $("#"+show).show();

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio"  name="type" value="solo" checked ;> solo<br>
    <input type="radio"  name="type" value="company" ;> company<br>

    <div id="solo" class="typechoice">Solo</div>
    <div id="company" class="typechoice">Company</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can extract the change function and call it when page is loaded:

```
function showDiv() {
    var show = $("input[name='type']:checked").val();
    $(".typechoice").hide();
    $("#"+show).show();

}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[name="type"]').on('change', showDiv)
    showDiv();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this, too:

```
$('#'+$('input[name="type"]:checked').val()).show();
```

Looks ugly, but it works.
Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/qnwudaeL/